# iptables закрыть всё, кроме 22,80 - тормозит

Tags: iptables

Есть небольшой сервер с сайтом:

```
apache 8080
nginx 80
mysql 3306
ssh 22
```

Необходимо закрыть всё, и оставить только 22 и 80.

Делаю как указано ниже:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 80,22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack -j ACCEPT  --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

В итоге всё работает, но появляются дикие тормоза. Сайт долго чего-то ждет, а потом грузится(и не всегда), без этих правил работает шустро. В этом и вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, тормозит DNS (не уверен, что он нужен веб-сайту, но всё же). Разрешите исходящие на UDP порт 53 (можно и на TCP порт 53).

Кроме того, откройте входящие и исходящие на интерфейсе `lo` для всех протоколов.

А ещё кроме того, из описанного непонятно, зачем у вас правила в FORWARD.

Comment: помогло, открыл локалку и тормоза ушли: iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 2):

`iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP` - так делать нельзя, нужно задавать правила по умолчанию:

```
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Читайте документацию, опасно использовать iptables без понимания.
У вас:

> ```
> iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
> ```

Правило пропускает только уже установленные соединения, новые создать не может, сайт скорее всего к чему то пытается обращаться и подвисает пока не отвалится по тайм ауту.

Можно попробовать такое правило и посмотреть куда и кто пытается подключиться:

```
 iptables -I OUTPUT -m state -p tcp --state NEW -m limit --limit 1/m --limit-burst 1 -j LOG --log-uid --log-prefix "Outbound Connection:  "
```

Comment: Спасибо, прописал стандартные правила вот так:

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT(открыл внешку)

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий конфиг без тормозов:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```